# Looping through data from returned service

Tags: angularjs

I have a subscribed to a service and need to loop through data returned from the service before outputting it to my view.

If I console log it out I get all the data requested but when I try to output it in the view I only get the last record in the data.

```
export class SandboxComponent implements OnInit {

  statusList;
  errorMessage;
  constructor(private dataService : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getStatusTag();
  }

  getStatusTag(){
    this.dataService.getStatusAPI()
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            for(let myVar of data){
              this.statusList = myVar;
              console.log(this.statusList);
            }
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

}
```

Comment: how do you loop in the view?

Comment: You are effectively assigning the last value from `data` to `this.statusList`, instead you might need to make `this.statusList` an **Array** and [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) values of `myVar` to it.

Answer (score 1):

this.statusList = myVar; Should be array

```
  this.statusList.push(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use map before subscribe to log single data and make some transformation to your data.

```
getStatusTag(){
    this.dataService.getStatusAPI()
    .map(response =>{
     // below you can log a single data
     console.log(response);
     return response.json()
     })
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
             // below you can log all data
             console.log(data);
             this.statusList = data;
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Comment: What if you want to log more `data.status` `data.location` and `data.sublocation`? Can you do it with the one subscribe method? or would you need to make a new method for each called `getStatus.subscribe()` `getLocation.subscribe()` and a `getSubLocation.subscribe()`?

Comment: in .map method you can do console.log(response.status) and console.log(response.location)